# Using Selenium RC, Excel (Data Driven) and SeleniumException

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-rc, data-driven-tests

I'm working on an automation project right now which is to create an account on a specific site.
There are different set of rules that needs to be checked. There needs to be a set of data where some of the required fields are missing, the email address used to create on the account is already used on the system and the last set is where the account could be created. The general flow of the process is:

1. Run SeleniumRC
2. Get Data from ExcelFile

   The Excel Data is composed of different sets.
   Set A : Missing Required Fille
   Set B : Email address is already used
   Set B : Complete/Correct Data
3. Go the site.
4. Input all data.

   If set A :

   ```
   Then creation will not process.
   It will provide output:
       Row Number - Error
   ```

   If set B :

   ```
   Then creation will not process.
   It will provide output:
       Row Number - Error
   ```

   If set C :

   ```
   It will create account.
   ```

   Provide Screenshot ounce login
5. Go back to step 2 until all rows found on the Excel File is completely checked.
6. Output will be placed on another Excel File

I am able to run the process however that is if I am using a flag for each entry in the Excel File. This does defeat the purpose of checking the creation process works as expected.
My Selenium Command goes like this:

```
   public void test_CreateAccount() throws Exception {

    //Some code to data from Excel Sheet
    totalrows = s.getRows();
    int i = 1;

    while(i<totalrows){
    //Some command to set data to string names
    RowNum = s.getCell(0, i).getContents();
    FName = s.getCell(1, i).getContents();

    selenium.open // Go to a specific site
    selenium.click("css=a > img"); // click create account
                    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
                    selenium.type("name=q1557", FName);
                    selenium.type("name=q1558", LName);
                    selenium.type("name=q1578", JobTitle);
                    selenium.type("name=q1579", email1);
                    selenium.type("name=email_confirm", email2);
                    selenium.type("name=q1583", phone);
                    selenium.type("name=q1584", ext);
                    selenium.type("name=q1585", fax);
                    selenium.type("name=q1587", company);
                    selenium.select("name=q1588", organization);
                    selenium.type("name=q1591", address1);
                    selenium.type("name=q1592", address2);
                    selenium.type("name=q1593", city);
                    selenium.select("name=q1594",state);
                    selenium.type("name=q1595", other);
                    selenium.type("name=q1598", zip);
                    selenium.select("name=q1596", country);
                    selenium.type("name=q1599", password1);
                    selenium.type("name=password_confirm", password2);
                    selenium.type("name=q1600", question);
                    selenium.type("name=q1601", answer);
    selenium.click("name=submit_signup");    // click submit


    i = i + 1;
    }

}
```

When I run the command above, this does work. If data is SET A or B, then error occurred. If data is SET C, then it will create and then done.

In order to check all data within the Excel file or continue until end of totalrows, I placed a flag.

In the middle of the command I place something like

```
if(flag=1){ //input process only until submit button. }else
if(flag=2){ //input process only until submit button. }else{ create
}
```

I tried using try and catch with SeleniumException however it still does not work. Can you provide me with any idea on how to do this.